# How to reuse model framework code in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

There are some common layers with same architecture and I want to train them separately. My codes showed blew and I am worrying that my codes exactly construct and train one model but not two. In fact I want to train the two `common` layers separately and get two `common` layers with different weights.

Is my codes right? Or how should I do it?

```
def common():
    # some layers
    pass

out1 = common(input)
out2 = common(input)

loss1
loss2
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: If you don't specifically ask tensorflow to reuse variables (e.g. with `tf.variable_scope(scope, reuse=True)`), it will create new ones every time.

Here is extensive [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables) on this topic including a "Sharing variables" section.

**Reply to Comment below:** There is a stack of variable scopes. The top one (most recent in your back trace) will prevail. Interfaces that don't let you pass a `reuse` option explicitly look at in this top variable scope. Interfaces that do, effectively create a variable_scope for the duration of their execution.

I top variable scope that is created for you will fail if you attempt to create two variables with the same name.

```
a = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
b = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<...> 
ValueError: Variable v already exists, disallowed.
            Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? ...
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, and I still want to know more about variable sharing. The `common` function contains `tf.layer` with `reuse=none`and `tf.nn` with no parameter of `reuse` at the same time,  According to [tf.variable_scope](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope#__init__), `reuse=none` means the parent scope's reuse flag is inherited. I never specified the reuse flag, so what will be the parent scope's reuse flag? And `tf.nn` with no parameter of `reuse`, whether and how will it be reused or not?

Comment: The broader issue, therefore, is that I think the top level's reuse mode can only be `tf.AUTO_REUSE`, which means that variables are reused when I call `common` the second time because the two `common` calling is in the same variable scopes. Is my idea right? I hope that is wrong!! Looking forward to you reply!

Comment: Replied in main answer above.